# Rijndael Managed Issue

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have a problem with AES Rijndael Managed encryption in C#

I have a list of around 110,000 image filenames that I want to encrypt individually. I have written an algorithm that encrypts them all together and then a method that decrypts a single image.

The encryption method is as follows:

```
var saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);

// The key size for encrypting the images
int KEY_SIZE = 256;

// The initialization vector for encrypting the images
byte[] _initialisationVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("EAzjVfNrCzOoE7AI");

//Derives the key from the phrase and the salt
using(var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes))
{
    //use the AES Rijndael algorithm
    using(var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        //set the mode
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        //create an encryption object
        using(var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(KEY_SIZE / 8), _initialisationVectorBytes))
        {
            //loop through the images
            Parallel.ForEach(_sourceImages, image =>
            {
                //set the plain text bytes and the salt bytes
                var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(image.ImageID.ToString());
                var cipherText = string.Empty;

                if(_encryptImageFilenames)
                {
                    //create a memory stream
                    using(var cryptoMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //create a cryptographic stream
                        using(var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cryptoMemoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            //encrypt the image id
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cryptoMemoryStream.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    cipherText = image.ImageID.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works as far as I can tell really well. However when I run the following decryption method, The vast majority of images decrypt correctly however, some images decrypt incorrectly with weird characters, and some give a **"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"** error.

```
// The size of the key
const int KeySize = 256;

// Use the Rijndael Managed algorithm
RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

// The initialisation vector
byte[] initialisationVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("EAzjVfNrCzOoE7AI");

try
{
    //get the cipher text bytes and the salt bytes
    var cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    //Derives the key from the phrase and the salt
    using(var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt)))
    {
        //set the mode
        SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        //create an decryption object
        using(var decryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(password.GetBytes(KeySize / 8), initialisationVectorBytes))
        {
            //create a memory stream
            using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
            {
                //create a crypto stream
                using(var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    //decrypt the string
                    var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                    var decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

So with 110000 images I get a succesful decrypt for all but around 20-30 images, with the failures being one of the two errors earlier.

I cannot for the life of me see why as surely if there was an error in the encrypt method it would affect all images that have been encrypted?

**some examples:**

Plaintext  = **128784**

Ciphertext = **J2W/5Y1/nvnrpvaWIZhl6g==**

Decrypted  = **128784**

---

Plaintext  = **122875**

Ciphertext = **N+heUx57427Lk8/Ew10rsA==**

Decrypted  = **�\u0001\u0017275**

---

Plaintext  = **121693**

Ciphertext = **Zf70jcYCbHQqhd23NqD6yA==**

Decrypted  = **121693**

---

Plaintext  = **133456**

Ciphertext = **wzBgoDaTnGBEyQokI+l6Uw==**

Decrypted  = **"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"**

The password and salt used in these examples are:

**Password** = "!XbLg`p/0.9nyF?;jGf@nA;e19'TtVk?Ik.l*2=zy.9MYH:7Jmj[|*0N!"

**Salt** = "alkfdslkaj:H6D£*rWe!N,K;?sdoidnalks34334234*&(*£';"

Comment: You shortened the code too much. I suspect it's about the lifetime management of the decrypting `RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey` but I can't be sure this way.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the result of `symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(...)` can be used by multiple threads simultaneously in your `Parallel.ForEach(...)`. I would suggest trying to move this inside the parallel foreach so that each thread uses a separate crypto transform.